# How to rotate 3d object by swiping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a horizontal cylinder in my scene and I want to rotate it (in the z-axis) by swiping left and right, I've created this script but it didn't work, can you please tell me where's the problem?

```
public class SwipeControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform Cylinder;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            // GET TOUCH 0
            Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // APPLY ROTATION
            if (touch0.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                Cylinder.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, touch0.deltaPosition.x);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_can you please help me?_" is not a problem description, nor an answerable question. "_I think its not the best one_". Maybe not, but why would that matter? Why isn't it good enough, what is your actual problem? Please **edit** and improve your question in a way so that it is answerable.

Comment: @elgonzo I mean that the cylinder didn't rotate when swiping left and right

Comment: Is the cylinder not rotating *at all* or by very small angle? What are angles in the inspector when cylinder is selected? Maybe logging of `touch0.phase` and `deltaPosition` will bring necessary information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using touch or mouse when you're testing this swiping?

Touch only works for touches, not mouse clicks.

Have you tried using the mouse input to move it around?

```
public class SwipeControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform cylinder;
    private float sensitivity = 10f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            float xAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            cylinder.Rotate(0, -xAxis * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but when swiping left the cylinder rotate right and the opposite too!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try using -xAxis. It's now just using negative xAxis to do the rotation which should flip your values for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Cylinder` as the name of your variable, cause it's a class name for Unity primitive:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrimitiveType.Cylinder.html

*Edit:
As Stijn says, the code will work, but it's a bad practice name the variables exactly equal as some class name.*

So if you replace the name of your variable for `myCylinder` for example, and your code now looks like that:

```
public class SwipeControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform myCylinder;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            // GET TOUCH 0
            Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // APPLY ROTATION
            if (touch0.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                myCylinder.transform.Rotate(Vector3.Right, touch0.deltaPosition.x, Space.World);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Tell me if changing the name and setting the reference from Editor it works.

**EDIT:** 
Take care with the `Rotate` function, if you are entering 3 arguments, they should be  `Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);`

So you are are currently applying 0 degrees of difference!

Here is the documentation link to `Rotate` function, and all the differenct constructors and overload methods that you can use:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: I made those changes but the Cylinder still not rotating :(

Comment: I can't test it right now, but could you debug if is entering the "APPLY ROTATION" conditional? put some Debug.log("apply rotation"); inside the conditional, and tell me if it's printing the text.

Comment: @Taik I've updated the answer, take a look at the Rotate call!

Comment: Why would changing a variable name have any effect on the code? It may not be the best variable name, sure, but it doesn't matter as long as the code compiles.

Comment: @Stijn False, if you are using as a Variable Name, the same name as a Class Name, you are calling one instance of that class, which maybe you don't have. The only case to call objects through the class name, as far as I know, is if you are using the singleton pattern.

Comment: @Lotan when you have a variable named `Foo` and a class named `Foo`, writing `Foo.DoSomething()` will refer to the variable named `Foo`. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: @Stijn Just tried, you're right, it works (it's not the best practice, but it works cause the compiler can recognize the scope), I'll update my answer, thanks.